# How can I change the programming language in visual studio 2012 Express?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I want to start learning C#. I installed visual studio 2012 Express for Desktop but the deafault language is visual basic, I tried changing it using Tools > Import and Export settings, but then neither of the 3 choices when I proceed lets me choose an other programming language.

Comment: *default language is visual basic* - you have to create a new project (solution), where you choose language and architecture (winforms, wpf, etc.). Choose `C#`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When starting new project - choose C#_WinForm/WPF, VB, or C++.Net.